# Pasar una hora a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una tabla la cual tiene dos filas que son para horas, estan en formato time, en php las quiero pasar a string(para pasarlas a string en android studio), como lo hago? trate con

```
date('H:i:s', strtotime($clase['horatermino']))= $HoraTermino;
```

pero no sirvio, saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿que pasa si imprimes $clase['horatermino']? ¿Quieres almacenar algo en $HoraTermino?

Answer (score 1):

Sabiendo que usas *MySQL* te puedes valer de la función [convert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) tal cual lo específica la propia documentación:

> Esta función toma una expresión de cualquier tipo y produce como resultado un valor del tipo especificado.

Entonces deberás tener una estructura como esta:

```
SELECT ....., CONVERT(columna, TIPO_DATO_SALIDA)......
```

Como tu intención es mandar un *string* entonces podemos usar el tipo de dato `CHAR` cuya salida será una cadena de texto

Finalmente tu consulta directo en SQL debería lucir así:

```
SELECT CONVERT(horatermino, CHAR) FROM tuTabla;
```

Y de esta forma evitamos hacer *casteos* de valores en el lenguaje de programación y mandamos el dato formateado desde la petición al motor de bases de datos.

Comment: Gracias, la verdad lo habia arreglado pero tienes razón, mejor evito casteos. lo voy a probar

Comment: Avísame si quedo o no @FranciscaRata